# figure out why my RC4 Implementation doesent produce the correct result

Tags: c, encryption

Ok I am new to C, I have programmed in C# for around 10 years now so still getting used to the whole language, Ive been doing great in learning but im still having a few hickups, currently im trying to write a implementation of RC4 used on the Xbox 360 to encrypt KeyVault/Account data.

However Ive run into a snag, the code works but it is outputting the incorrect data, I have provided the original c# code I am working with that I know works and I have provided the snippet of code from my C project, any help / pointers will be much appreciated :)

Original C# Code :

```
public struct RC4Session
{
    public byte[] Key;
    public int SBoxLen;
    public byte[] SBox;
    public int I;
    public int J;
}


    public static RC4Session RC4CreateSession(byte[] key)
    {
        RC4Session session = new RC4Session
        {
            Key = key,
            I = 0,
            J = 0,
            SBoxLen = 0x100,
            SBox = new byte[0x100]
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < session.SBoxLen; i++)
        {
            session.SBox[i] = (byte)i;
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < session.SBoxLen; j++)
        {
            index = ((index + session.SBox[j]) + key[j % key.Length]) % session.SBoxLen;
            byte num4 = session.SBox[index];
            session.SBox[index] = session.SBox[j];
            session.SBox[j] = num4;
        }
        return session;
    }


    public static void RC4Encrypt(ref RC4Session session, byte[] data, int index, int count)
    {
        int num = index;
        do
        {
            session.I = (session.I + 1) % 0x100;
            session.J = (session.J + session.SBox[session.I]) % 0x100;
            byte num2 = session.SBox[session.I];
            session.SBox[session.I] = session.SBox[session.J];
            session.SBox[session.J] = num2;
            byte num3 = data[num];
            byte num4 = session.SBox[(session.SBox[session.I] + session.SBox[session.J]) % 0x100];
            data[num] = (byte)(num3 ^ num4);
            num++;
        }
        while (num != (index + count));
    }
```

Now Here is my own c version :

```
    typedef struct rc4_state {
         int s_box_len;
         uint8_t* sbox;
         int i;
         int j;
     } rc4_state_t;
     unsigned char* HMAC_SHA1(const char* cpukey, const unsigned char* hmac_key) {
         unsigned char* digest = malloc(20);

         digest = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), cpukey, 16, hmac_key, 16, NULL, NULL);

         return digest;
     }
     void rc4_init(rc4_state_t* state, const uint8_t *key, int keylen)
     {
         state->i = 0;
         state->j = 0;
         state->s_box_len = 0x100;
         state->sbox = malloc(0x100);

         // Init sbox.
         int i = 0, index = 0, j = 0;
         uint8_t buf;
         while(i < state->s_box_len) {
             state->sbox[i] = (uint8_t)i;
             i++;
         }
         while(j < state->s_box_len) {
             index = ((index + state->sbox[j]) + key[j % keylen]) % state->s_box_len;
             buf = state->sbox[index];
             state->sbox[index] = (uint8_t)state->sbox[j];
             state->sbox[j] = (uint8_t)buf;
             j++;
         }
     }

   void rc4_crypt(rc4_state_t* state, const uint8_t *inbuf, uint8_t **outbuf, int buflen)
     {
         int idx = 0;
         uint8_t num, num2, num3;

         *outbuf = malloc(buflen);
         if (*outbuf) {  // do not forget to test for failed allocation
             while(idx != buflen) {
                 state->i = (int)(state->i + 1) % 0x100;
                 state->j = (int)(state->j + state->sbox[state->i]) % 0x100;
                 num = (uint8_t)state->sbox[state->i];
                 state->sbox[state->i] = (uint8_t)state->sbox[state->j];
                 state->sbox[state->j] = (uint8_t)num;
                 num2 = (uint8_t)inbuf[idx];
                 num3 = (uint8_t)state->sbox[(state->sbox[state->i] + (uint8_t)state->sbox[state->j]) % 0x100];
                 (*outbuf)[idx] = (uint8_t)(num2 ^ num3);
                 printf("%02X", (*outbuf)[idx]);
                 idx++;
             }
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
```

Usage (c#) :

```
         byte[] cpukey = new byte[16]
        {
            ...
        };
        byte[] hmac_key = new byte[16]
        {
            ...
        };

        byte[] buf = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(cpukey).ComputeHash(hmac_key);
        MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(buf).Replace("-", ""), "");
```

Usage(c):

```
const char cpu_key[16] = { 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX };
const unsigned char hmac_key[16] = { ... };
unsigned char* buf = HMAC_SHA1(cpu_key, hmac_key);

uint8_t buf2[20];
uint8_t buf3[8] = { 0x1E, 0xF7, 0x94, 0x48, 0x22, 0x26, 0x89, 0x8E }; // Encrypted Xbox 360 data
uint8_t* buf4;

// Allocated 8 bytes out.
buf4 = malloc(8);
int num = 0; 
while(num < 20) {
    buf2[num] = (uint8_t)buf[num]; // convert const char
    num++;
}

rc4_state_t* rc4 = malloc(sizeof(rc4_state_t));

rc4_init(rc4, buf2, 20);
rc4_crypt(rc4, buf3, &buf4, 8);
```

Now I have the HMACsha1 figured out, im using openssl for that and I confirm I am getting the correct hmac/decryption key its just the rc4 isnt working, Im trying to decrypt part of the Kyevault that should == "Xbox 360"||"58626F7820333630"

The output is currently : "0000008108020000" I do not get any errors in the compilation, again any help would be great ^.^

Thanks to John's help I was able to fix it, it was a error in the c# version, thanks John !

Comment: It looks like this sub-expression in your C code: `key[j % 20]` does not match the analogous sub-expression in your C# code: `key[j % key.Length]`.  That might not be the issue for your particular test case, but it seems likely to be *an* issue.

Comment: I made that static, as the input key length is 20 and always will be, I cannot I think it might be a casting issue but still looking through it.

Comment: If you're using a fixed key length, then it is worse than useless to pass the key length as a function argument.

Comment: Fixed, your right it was a mistake I changed that while debugging to see if it was that thanks for point that out :)

Comment: You appear to have a classic memory allocation problem.  You pass `outbuf`, a `uint8_t *`, to function `rc4_crypt()`.  Because the argument (`buf4`) is an uninitialized pointer variable, this is passing an indeterminate pointer value ***by value*** (C has *only* pass by value).  You do assign a value to `outbuf` inside the function, but that has no effect on the value of `buf4` in the caller (because pass by value).  You leak that memory, and `buf4`'s value remains indeterminate.

Comment: Sorry John I forgot to write the original snippet and just quickly wrote some usage, I have pasted the original code (without the static bytes of cpu key and hmac data) but both are 16 bytes each.

Comment: The problem I pointed out is not fundamentally changed by the altered usage.  Function `rc4_crypt()` *allocates its own output buffer*, ignoring the pointer you pass to it.  The pointer to that buffer is not communicated back to the caller.

Comment: Ahh thank you, but it is still incorrect output "77D776CC77D77600" :(

Comment: The `printf()` output of `rc4_crypt()` does not reflect the encrypted data, at all.  Each byte you output is the as-yet unset value of the *next* position you intend to write.  This is an output problem, not a computational one.  Move the `num++` to the very end of the loop to fix it.

Comment: Inasmuch as you seem still to not be getting the expected output, I have to ask you to present how you are using the C# version that is serving as a reference implementation for you.  It may be that there is also some kind of difference there.

Comment: Updated, I only used the above statement to get the correct key, since I have already decrypted the keyvault data, I have the original crypted (which I took the original data from) and the unencrypted version (I know it says Xbox 360), ive been looking at this for 3 hours now and still cannot figure it out :(

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really help.  Additionally, I don't think there's much more I can do for you.  As far as I can determine, the C code you now have performs the same computation as your C# code, given equivalent input.  If you're getting different output than you expect then I'm going to attribute that to differences in the input.

Comment: Its the input, it works correct, its down to the way i handle the key data, im still tracing what ive done wrong in the c# version, so it all works thanks to you John, no more help needed :)

Answer (score 1):

As I remarked in comments, your main problem appeared to involve how the output buffer is managed.  You have since revised the question to fix that, but I describe it anyway here, along with some other alternatives for fixing it.  The remaining problem is discussed at the end.

Function `rc4_crypt()` allocates an output buffer for itself, but it has no mechanism to communicate a pointer to the allocated space back to its caller.  Your revised usage furthermore exhibits some inconsistency with `rc4_crypt()` with respect to how the output buffer is expected to be managed.

There are three main ways to approach the problem.

1. Function `rc4_crypt()` presently returns nothing, so you could let it continue to allocate the buffer itself, and modify it to return a pointer to the allocated output buffer.
2. You could modify the type of the `outbuf` parameter to `uint8_t **` to enable `rc4_crypt()` to set the caller's pointer value indirectly.
3. You could rely on the caller to manage the output buffer, and make `rc4_crypt()` just write the output via the pointer passed to it.

The only one of those that might be tricky for you is #2; it would look something like this:

```
void rc4_crypt(rc4_state_t* state, const uint8_t *inbuf, uint8_t **outbuf, int buflen) {
    *outbuf = malloc(buflen);
    if (*outbuf) {  // do not forget to test for failed allocation
        // ...
        (*outbuf)[idx] = (uint8_t)(num2 ^ num3);
        // ...
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
rc4_crypt(rc4, buf3, &buf4, 8);
```

... without otherwise allocating any memory for `buf4`.

The caller in any case has the responsibility for freeing the output buffer when it is no longer needed.  This is clearer when it performs the allocation itself; you should document that requirement if `rc4_crypt()` is going to be responsible for the allocation.

---

The remaining problem appears to be strictly an output problem.  You are apparently relying on print statements in `rc4_crypt()` to report on the encrypted data.  I have no problem whatever with debugging via print statements, but you *do* need to be careful to print the data you actually want to examine.  In this case you do not.  You update the joint buffer index `idx` at the end of the encryption loop *before* printing a byte from the output buffer.  As a result, at each iteration you print not the encrypted byte value you've just computed, but rather an indeterminate value that happens to be in the *next* position of the output buffer.

Move the `idx++` to the very end of the loop to fix this problem, or change it from a `while` loop to a `for` loop and increment `idx` in the third term of the loop control statement.  In fact, I strongly recommend `for` loops over `while` loops where the former are a good fit to the structure of the code (as here); I daresay you would not have made this mistake if your loop had been structured that way.

Comment: Genuinly john thank you for all your help, i made simple mistakes but it must be a compution error in rc4 crypt, I modifed the mistakes (Ill update the original) and it outputs "624AF65892273BB0" now, I mean I might have read your answer wrong here also and im probably still outputting the incorrect values. plus the only reason I didnt use for over while is it complained to much, I know I could pass the -gnu99 flag to the makefile as im building on ubuntu/rasbain.